# How do you calculate the sample variance of an infinite population?

Tags: probability, statistics

I searched for it all over the web but all I could find was the formula for a finite population. Does a formula for the sample variance of an infinite population even exist?

Comment: Isn't a sample finite?

Comment: You're confusing categories. You're either talking about the population, in which case you're talking about parameters which describe the population. Or, you're talking about the sample, in which case you're talking about statistics that describe the sample. Most parameters have corresponding statistics, but the concepts are quite distinct, and this distinction is of fundamental importance in statistics. As coffeemath has already mentioned, a sample is finite, and you can quite easily calculate its variance.